# What does size limit on MySQL index mean?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`info` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`some_more_info` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `my_index` (`some_more_info`,`info`(24)),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My question is about the second key called `my_index`. What does the "(24)" size limit mean? The actual size of the column is 50, but the index is only 24 characters.

Does this mean that MySQL indexes only the first 24 characters of the column `info`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes, the first 24 characters are taken into consideration to build the BTree index. Indexing limits are assigned to text types such as varchar and text, as they don't affect numeric precision.

Comment: See the 
[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/create-index.html) and look at the comments about "Indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column values..."

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
The entire description about the index length can be found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

> Prefix lengths are given in characters for nonbinary string types and
>   in bytes for binary string types. That is, index entries consist of
>   the **first length characters** of each column value for CHAR, **VARCHAR**,
>   and TEXT columns, and the first length bytes of each column value for
>   BINARY, VARBINARY, and BLOB columns.

Also you create query has/had some extra ,'s.